# How to upload a file from IsolatedStorage to SkyDrive?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive, live-sdk

I am trying to upload a text file, myFile.txt, to SkyDrive. Below is the code:

```
private async void btnUpload_Click( object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    Client = new LiveConnectClient( _session );
    string filename = "myFile.txt";

    var isolatedstorageFile= await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync( filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting );

    using ( StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( await isolatedstorageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync() ) )
    {
        // convert to string
        var _String = Serialize( "this is a test file" );
        await writer.WriteAsync( _String );
    }

    await Client.BackgroundUploadAsync( FolderID, new Uri( isolatedstorageFile.Path ), OverwriteOption.Overwrite );
}
```

FolderID is global and has the value of: "folder.17ff6230f5f26b89.17FF6230F5F26B89!1533"

The problem is in defining the second parameter of the BackgroundUploadAsync. How do I solve it, i.e. specify the URI of where "myFile.txt" IsolatedStorage file is?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing 3 arguments in `BackgroundUploadAsync` where first one is FolderId, and second is path of the file, which is wrong check the [documentation first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/jj219363.aspx), second argument takes the file name only not the Path of file and the third one is the stream of file.

Also You can use `UploadAsync` instead `BackgroundUploadAsync`.

```
    IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    var res = await client.UploadAsync(folderId, FileName, isfs, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
```

Comment: His call to `BackgroundUploadAsync` is correct, that's how it's done in Windows Phone. The problem is in Uri passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx) for refrence.

You are getting problem on upload, i guess it is because you are trying to upload file which is not in shared/transfer folder in isolated storage. so just create file in shared/transfer and then try to upload file to sky drive.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload the file from isolated storage using the `BackgroundUploadAsync` method, you need the correct URI to the file. The path to access files stored in isolated storage is `/shared/transfers/`. So, to pass the URI parameter to the method,  preppend `/shared/transfers/` to the file name. That will be the valid URI. See below:

```
await Client.BackgroundUploadAsync(FolderID, new Uri("/shared/transfers/" + fileName, UriKind.Relative), OverwriteOption.Overwrite );
```

The other option is to use the `UploadAsync` method and attach the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the pointers I got. Rewrote the function and it is like this:

```
    private async void btnUpload_Click( object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
        string filename = "myFile.txt";

        StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync( "Shared", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists );
        folder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync( "transfers", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists );

        var isolatedstorageFile= await folder.CreateFileAsync( filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting );
        using ( StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( await isolatedstorageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync() ) )
            {
            // convert to string
            var _String = Serialize( "this is a test file" );
            await writer.WriteAsync( _String );
            }

        await LiveHelper.Client.BackgroundUploadAsync( FolderID, new Uri( "/shared/transfers/" + filename, UriKind.Relative ), OverwriteOption.Overwrite );
        }


    private static string Serialize( object objectToSerialize )
        {
        using ( MemoryStream _Stream = new MemoryStream() )
            {
            try
                {
                var _Serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer( objectToSerialize.GetType() );
                _Serializer.WriteObject( _Stream, objectToSerialize );
                _Stream.Position = 0;
                StreamReader _Reader = new StreamReader( _Stream );
                return _Reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            catch ( Exception e )
                {
                Debug.WriteLine( "\n******** Serialize:" + e.Message );
                return string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
```

The file was uploaded in the correct FolderID.

Eitan

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file into Skydrive, the file should be saved inside "/shared/transfers/" folder in IsolatedStorage. LiveConnectClient can only upload/download files from/to "/shared/transfers/".